# Activate div function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to activate a function on click on a div ... actually this animation starts @page load... and i want to click on a div to activate this animation.

this was my first Question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080983/activate-div-function-on-click/21081003#21081003)

How is this possible?

```
var $a = $(".a"),
$b = $(".b"),
$c = $(".c");

function anim1() {
    $b.animate({width: 395}, {duration: 500, complete: anim2});
}

function anim2() {
    $a.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 500});
}


anim1();
```

Here is the fiddle: [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/26/)

Comment: you mean execute or trigger by `activate` ?

Comment: Please read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/. Its whole purpose is to explain jQuery basics (like binding event handlers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".example").click(function() {
    anim1();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/27/)

Comment: Thank you so much! :)) That's what i want :)

Comment: @LorDex On SO there's some grace time involved before allowing the OP to mark an answer as *correct*. Be patient ;)

Comment: @andre34 why not simply like `$c.click(anim1);`

Comment: I think he just forgot to mark as accepted if we consider the "Thank you so much! :)) That's what i want :)" comment.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan `$c.click(anim1);` can be useless if he sets the width or height of the `div.c` improperly.

Comment: @kgd no, `$c.click(anim1);` is the exact shorthand of your code. Taking in consideration that `$c` is the trigger element (err... which is probably not now after I've seen the demo fiddle :) ).